# Why is my external hard drive showing up as read only every now and then?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I'm using Windows 10 Professional and have an external USB hard drive that is used for backups. From time to time this hard drive becomes read only. I found out, that I can remove this read only state with `diskpart`:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk #  (while # ist the number of my disk)
attributes disk clear readonly
```

My question what might be the reason for the hard disk drive becoming read only?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen on a few drives when there are driver issues or the drive is starting to fail (firmware/controller board issue) but its not very common. The most common reason this occurs is due to someone setting the drive as write protected or due to malware.

**Test Driver**

1. go to device manager
2. locate the external hard drive
3. right click on it and choose uninstall (delete the driver)
4. reboot, windows will detect the external hard drive and install the driver

**Malware**

When you knotice the drive is write protected try going to safe mode and see if it becomes non-write protected.
Start your computer in safe mode and check to see if the drive is write protected. if it is not write protected in safe mode then a software (malware) is causing the issue. Download a good anti-virus/malware/spyware software and run a few scans

**On Domain/Work Computer**

Since you are on Win 10 Pro its likely you are also on a computer that is connected to a business domain. If this is the case your IT department might have a script to block write access to external drives (to keep data secure).

Does this occur on connect/disconnect of the drive. Try wiping the properties like normal and then after its saved remove the device and reconnect. If it does auto write protect then it could be a IT script running on your computer that does this.

If this is the case contact your IT department and talk to them about getting an exception